# Unused argument in summarise n() R

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

I am trying to run the following code:

```
 DF2 %>%

 group_by(doy, yearadded) %>%

 summarise(n_entries= n(doy, yearadded))
```

Which gives me the error:

```
Error in n(doy, yearadded) : unused arguments (doy, yearadded)
```

My yearadded field is a character class and doy is a numeric, is that why it's not working or is there some other reason?

Comment: You don't need any arguments in `n`.  It should be `n()`  The syntax is `summarise(n_entries = n())` which can also be written as `count(DF2, doy, yearadded)`

Comment: Oh thank you, much easier than I expected

Answer (score 5):

The `n()` doesn't take any arguments.  It would  be

```
library(dplyr)
DF2 %>%
 group_by(doy, yearadded) %>%
 summarise(n_entries= n())
```

---

Or more compactly

```
count(DF2, doy, yearadded)
```