# Summarise does not accept counts()

Tags: r, dplyr

I am creating a summary data frame for multiple columns with dplyr, and it works well for desired functions excepts for count or n(). I want to show total number of observations.

```
 summ <- Test_data %>%            
   summarize(across(
     .cols = is.numeric,
     .fns = list(a=n(),mean=mean, stdev=sd, max=max,min=min), na.rm=TRUE,
     .names = "{col}_{fn}"
   ))
```

It gives error:
Error: Problem with `summarise()` input `..1`.x Can't convert an integer vector to function
i Input `..1` is `across(...)`.

Why just function for counts does not work, please advise.

Comment: related 1: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45024158/using-n-at-the-same-time-as-calculating-other-summary-statistics

Comment: related 2: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068522/summarize-all-with-n-function

Comment: related 3: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22801153/dplyr-error-in-n-function-should-not-be-called-directly?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: related 4: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55259295/unused-argument-in-summarise-n-r

Comment: related 5: https://stackoverflow.com/q/60249276/7941188

Comment: In short: using n() in summarise is tricky. There are workarounds. See those threads. Plenty of answers

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I saw few other link which you suggest here, I did not get this one earlier though which is what I needed. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068522/summarize-all-with-n-function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @tjebo comments, `n()` is tricky inside of a `summarize()`.

This is discussed the comment he linked - [summarize_all with "n()" function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58068522/summarize-all-with-n-function) - where @akrun explains "getting the n() for each column is not making much sense as it would be the same [for each summarized column]." The reason `n()` is giving you problems is because `n()` doesn't take any arguments, but the summarize is sending the value of the selected `.cols` as an argument.

Two solutions are to replace with the `length` function, or add a leading `~` to turn `n()` into `~ n()`. (However, I don't know why `~ n()` works, is it turning the code into a single-sided formulae? )

Also, use `where(is.numeric)` in the column selection.

```
iris %>% 
    summarize(across(.cols  = where(is.numeric), 
                     .fns   = list(n = ~ n(), mean = mean, sd = sd), 
                     .names = "{col}_{fn}"))

iris %>% 
    summarize(across(.cols  = where(is.numeric), 
                     .fns   = list(n = length, mean = mean, sd = sd), 
                     .names = "{col}_{fn}"))
```

Comment: Can you explain why n() is working with the leading tilde sign in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Solution suggested works, but I can't understand the reason for n() not working in summarise, is it related with groupby which I am not using?